# How should the eyes be arranged adapted for astronomical observations?

Tags: biology, creature-design, hard-science, super-powers

Since ancient times, the phenomenon of "telescopic vision" has been known, when in clear calm weather, astronomers can distinguish details in the starry sky that are not visible to most people.  At the beginning of the 20th century, a case was recorded when an astronomer with the naked eye established the location of two satellites of Jupiter (628.1 million km from Earth), and Saturn (1276.1 million km from Earth) seemed to him "flattened", which was later confirmed by astronomical optical instruments.

At least the priests of the Malian Dogon people claim that they have been observing the triple star Sirius (8.8 light-years from Earth) with the naked eye for more than 1000 years, the constellation Canis Major and other "stellar spiral worlds" (galaxies), first sketched as "nebulae  ”By astronomer W. Ross in the mid-19th century and described in detail as“ star clusters ”in 1924 by astronomer Edwin Hubble after“ night vigils ”at Mount Wilson Observatory (California).

This brings us to the heart of my question:
What should my superman's ( genetically modified human ) eyes be, specially designed for astronomical and telescopic observations?

Comment: It’s completely implausible that anyone could see the moons of Mars with the naked eye. They’re far far smaller than the major moons of Jupiter, where naked-eye visibility _is_ plausible. The apparent magnitude of the brighter one, Phobos, peaks at about 11.3, and naked-eye visibility stops before 8 even with exceptional eyesight (and nothing else bright, like Mars, nearby).

Comment: Do you have any reference to ancient Greeks knowing about Mars's moons? I've always heard that Galileo was the first person to see the moons of other planets, with a telescope.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is based upon UTTERLY FALSE premises. Mars's moons cannot be seen naked-eye from earth. trees and cars cannot be seen nakedeye from orbit. Nor houses, Unless they are really, really large. *with binoculars*, something as small as a Boeing 747 on the ground is just barely visible.

Comment: Fixed, do you know the answer to this question?

Comment: The satellites of Jupiter are right at the outer limit of naked eye observation for people with exceptionally good vision; that somebody can separate them with the naked eye is remarkable, but not supernatural. The Dogons are fabulating, which is completely ordinary for a people with no writing. Superman's eyes *cannot* be all that much better than ordinary human eyes, unless they are *huge*. The limit of astronomical observations is given *directly* by the physical size of the objective lens; the entry pupil of human eyes is 9mm wide maximum; a *cheap* amateur telescope *starts* at 60 mm.

Comment: Do not confuse comic-book physics with anything in the real world. Superman can look at Mars and see individual grains of sand, because comics, if the writer needs him too. This is impossible (from Earth) in the real world.

Comment: Not a superman from American comics, but a superman (Nietzsche) (a genetically modified person who surpasses us in one area or another.

This is a bug in the translator software.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of physics.

Light is a wave. This means that when light passes through an aperture, it will *difract*. This means that a point source of light *cannot* be imaged as a point, *not even by an ideal lens*. (An ideal lens is a lens free of [aberrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_aberration). Such a lens cannot be made physically, so that the separation power of any physical lens will be worse than the separation power of an ideal lens of the same diameter.)

The best possible separation power (that is, the minimum angle of view between two point sources of light such that their images are distinguishable) of an *ideal* lens with a physical diameter $d$ is given by the [Airy formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk):

$$\theta = \arcsin 1.22\frac {\lambda}{d}$$

where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light emitted by the point sources. (The result is in radians, for those who wonder.)

Plugging in 9 mm as the maximum diameter of a dark adapted human eye pupil, and considering $\lambda = 555\,\text{nm}$ (green light for maximum sensitivity) we get that the separation power of a human-sized eye cannot be better than

$$\arcsin 1.22 \frac{555 \times 10^{-9}}{9 \times 10^{-3}} \approx 15''$$

The separation power of a normal human eye (= the eye of a person with normal vision) is considered to be about one arc-minute.

- The satellites of Jupiter are right at the outer limit of naked eye observation for people with exceptionally good vision; that somebody can separate them with the naked eye is remarkable, but not supernatural.

  (The maximum angular separations between the Galilean moons and Jupiter are between 2′ and 10′, more than enough for the naked eye to resolve; the difficulty of seeing them with the naked eye is not due to lack of acuity, but rather to the great difference between the brightness of Jupiter and its moons. Jupiter has an apparent magnitude of −1.66 when in opposition with the Sun, while the Galilean moons have magnitudes between 4.6 and 5.6. Simply put, Jupiter is so bright that the poor moons get sunk in the black background.)
- The Dogons are fabulating, which is completely ordinary for a people with no writing. Superman's eyes *cannot* be all that much better than ordinary human eyes, unless they are *huge*.

  (My favorite is that the Dogons, who supposedly knew that Sirius is a triple star, *could not even point out Sirius* -- and Sirius is *the* brightest star in the night sky.)
- The limit of astronomical observations is given *directly* by the physical size of the objective lens; the entry pupil of human eyes is 9mm wide maximum; a *cheap* amateur telescope *starts* at 60 mm.

Comment: Thank you, but could you point out biological changes in the structure of the human eye in order to be able to see these objects well?  (definitely better than ordinary people can see)

Comment: @FrenchThompson3: I don't fully understand what you want. The visual acuity of the human eye *cannot* be increased by more than a factor of about 4; unless you accept making the eyes much larger. That bright objects drown out dim objects nearby is an unfortunate result of how optical sensors work, not much we can do there. (Strong light diffuses through the separation between individual light sensitive elements.) The essence of the answer is that human eyes are already pretty good for their size, and at absolute best we could make them four times better at distinguishing small details.

Comment: Suppose that the eyes become 8-10 times larger than those of ordinary people (my superhumans are three meters tall and their eyes can really be proportionally larger than those of ordinary people, and be comparable to those that you could see in a tarsier), then how well they could  to see (example)?

Comment: @FrenchThompson3: I gave the formula for an ideal lens. I also gave the practical example of human visual acuity compared to the ideal. What more is needed?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid what you want is not practical.  It's not precisely impossible, but it's so impractical that you cannot build a creature (let alone a humanoid) capable of what you want.

You need to understand some basics of the limitations of Earth-bound astronomical observations to see why.

Regarding some of the claims you mention made by people, keep in mind that an embarrassing number of professional astronomers at one point claimed to be able to see (and even map !) canals on Mars.  There are, of course, no canals they could have seen, but the power of self-convincing yourself is about the only superpower human really possess.  So treat such reports with skepticism.

There are three main limitations of resolving power at visual wavelengths.  The first one was explained by [AlexP in his answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/189300/32391).  I won't go into this again, but it basically means you need an enormously large device to focus light and be able to resolve detail at a given wavelength.

The second reason is the atmosphere.  You will often seen astronomers discuss good viewing conditions.  What an astronomer means by this is that they can resolve a planet like Mars into a somewhat blurry ball with only the largest features on the planet (e.g. like Jupiter's Red Spot) able to be made out.  The atmosphere you have to look through means that any light reaching the atmosphere is distorted by gazillions of tiny air movements and interactions and you quite simply cannot resolve real detail.

The third reason is the number of photons reaching you.  Light from stars is driven by powerful internal fusion reactions and is relatively strong but planets, etc. rely on reflected light to be visible.  That means the light has to reach the planet, is weak by the time it gets there and then just that tiny bit of reflected light is spread out over all possible angles and we only get an even smaller fraction of that light when it gets to Earth.  And even that gets reduced further by the atmosphere.  To put that in perspective, to measure the distance to the Moon precisely, NASA put a special reflector on the surface of the Moon and fire a powerful laser at it (aimed by a powerful telescope), and what they get back is on the order of about one photon per second.  This is why optics have to be so large - they have to gather a lot of photons from a large area to make even a faint image of things possible.

So what does this mean in practice ?

A good image of Mars at it's closest approach to us in decades taken with a very good amateur telescope by someone who is experienced and patient and understands what they are doing would be something like this :

[image]

This is explained is considerable detail in [Thunderfoot's excellent video on observing Mars on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8dPnkN3rwc).

As he explains this resolution is below the threshold described in AlexP's post, which is a theoretical limit without other limiting effects.

The telescope used by Thunderfoot for that image was an 11" Cassegrain and that's a lot of optics.  You won't build a humanoid with that amount of optical power or anything approaching it.

I am afraid that any hard-science notion of real humanoid (astronomical) telescopic vision is not realistic.

In practical terms humans *have* evolved a system to enable them to do this : it's called *thinking*.  We have evolved brains that are good are making tools to enable us to surpass our frail human limitations.  We do not need to evolved anything else, we just need to keep using our brains.  That *is* the hard science answer.  A pair of good binoculars is frankly a really good solution to extend human vision the way you want.  In a sense we "evolved" binoculars and telescopes for that purpose.

Also in practical hard-science terms there is no evolutionary advantage to evolving the eyesight you want.  What use is it ?  It won't keep you safer, it won't help you find food or hunt better.  It will add a significant vulnerability to you as such large optics will be a real handicap in any situations you are in danger in.  That last point makes it an evolutionary dead-end.  These are the reasons that *no* creature on Earth has evolved what you describe.

So hard-science does not provide a method to solve your problem.  On the contrary, it makes it unworkable and unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

If you had a different anatomy though, things might work out differently.
A creature with a large body, that is covered with eyes, could form a lenseless, huge eye at night.

It would get even more wild, if you had a hive mind creature with photo realistic memory. They could observe a planet moving before a sun, from different points of view on a planet, and then merge that memory into a observation with a parallax the size of a planet.

Comment: hard-science

Requires answers backed up by equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, other citations, etc. Contrast with: science-based and reality-check tags. This tag should never be the only tag on a question because this tag frames how a question should be answered, not the topic. Review the tag info before using this tag, and flag your question for moderator attention once posted to have the hard-science notice added.

Comment: a expanded paralax is actually a quite well researched topic. relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/941/    . Hard science doesen't mean you have to limit your imagination. It just means you got to have a good, working explanation when put to the question.

Comment: Actually [tag:hard-science] *does* mean you need to provide more than an opinion.  You do need a more solid scientific foundation for your answer and references to external papers or mathematics illustrating your point are really required.  Imaginative answers are not appropriate unless you back them with real science.

Comment: Okay, here we go. Hiveminds are sort of realistic. Here are two canadian Siamese twins who share thoughts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krista_and_Tatiana_Hogan. Lots of speculation in the hard-scifi of peter watts builds on something along this. Creatures with distributed nervous system and perception are not realistic- they are real. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuttlefish . This should do though. I cant plug every hole in every education system?